# Framework missing from System but not XCode on Mac/iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, frameworks, messageui

I'm working with a Qt project on a Mac. I have to add a framework

> MessagesUI.Framework

to the XCode list of frameworks each and every time that I open the project or try to archive it. Is there a way to keep it as a required default so I won't have to add it every time?

I've tried changing the search path but that doesn't seem to work, and it is included in the project files that its used in, within Qt.

> `#import <ContactsUI/ContactsUI.h>`
>
> `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>`

I also have it linked directly within the .pro file - another framework is successfully added that way.

> `INCLUDEPATH += /...File/Path.../System/Library/Frameworks
>       QMAKE_LFLAGS += - /...File/Path.../System/Library/Frameworks
>       LIBS += -framework ContactsUI
>       LIBS += -framework MessageUI`

UPDATE: It appears that MessageUI.framework is missing from the System frameworks, but not from the XCode frameworks. ContactsUI.framework works, no issue there. Looks as though XCode won't allow me to add a framework from the XCode files, only from System files. ContactsUI.framework was also causing a problem prior to adding its address to the .pro file, but IS in System frameworks.

Comment: are you using cocoapods to add framworks?

Comment: @MRizwan33 not to my knowledge.

Comment: I have given answer it describes how you can use it. if it solves your problem then please accept the answer.

Comment: @MRizwan33 I can't accept the answer as I'm still stuck and I haven't been able to find any useful description in relation to my problem. How do I fix this without cocoapods? How do I get MessageUI.framework back into the System Framework files?

Answer (score 0):

Use Cocoapods for adding frameworks in Xcode project. This is mostly used way for developers. Here is the link how to use it. [Click Here](https://cocoapods.org/)

Comment: How will this fix the fact that System doesn't have the framework? Isn't there a way to simply copy the framework file into the folder? I am brand new to using a Mac.

Comment: when you press cmd+b this will automatically add frameworks by its own. After that you can import the library which you have added in its pod file. try to learn how you can use it. @SamTheTester

Comment: every developer uses cocoapods. it doesn't make your project heavy as compare to manually adding the frameworks.

Comment: There's got to be a simpler way than installing another program? Isn't there a way to point to the folder in XCode?

Comment: This is the simplest way man. other is just drag and drop your project into xcode and tick mark the option says "Copy items if needed"

Answer (score 0):

Cleared Derived Data and discovered a few small (but major) spelling mistakes.

Cocoapods was not necessary to solve this problem.